# Is the transfer tag too broad?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is the [transfer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transfer) tag too broad? It seems to add no value compared to just using the `transfer` keyword in a title or body. Right now this is the barebones tag info:

> To move something from one thing to another.

Most of the questions currently tagged with [transfer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transfer) would probably be better suited to using [domain-transfer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-transfer). That tag is good for topics like EPP keys, authorization codes, and migration of WHOIS data.

And then there are some questions that probably don't need the [transfer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transfer) tag at all.

- [PDF download fails because of...what?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/105600/pdf-download-fails-because-of-)

Comment: Note that the "transfer" tag was removed from the question in the above link  since it didn't really apply as Nic had pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does seem like a number of questions using the [transfer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btransfer%5D+is%3Aq) tag really should be using the more specific and commonly used [domain-transfer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdomain-transfer%5D+is%3Aq) tag. Other questions using the [transfer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btransfer%5D+is%3Aq) tag that aren't related to domain-transfers includes topics such as:

- [Data transfers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27325/how-do-i-get-a-tb-of-data-to-a-new-web-server) to or from a server
- [Email transfers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26828/transferring-maildir-emails-to-another-server) to another server
- [Website/Blog transfers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12853/how-to-transfer-a-blogspot-blog-to-a-new-domain) to another server or service
- [Website ownership transfers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13630/what-do-i-need-to-know-about-selling-a-website) to another party
- [Google Analytics/Search Console account transfers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59064/transfer-ownership-of-abandoned-google-analytics-account) to another party
- And so on...

Tags [get created](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) by users just by adding them to questions, so even if we deleted the `transfer` tag and replaced it with more specific tags such as `data-transfer`, we couldn't prevent users in the future from recreating and using the `transfer` tag again.

In the general case of *transferring* something, it seems the combination of two tags (e.g., `data` + `transfer`) might be more suitable than trying to conceive of each `___-transfer` tag possible, while trying to prevent users from adding the `transfer` tag back again.

Since the `domain-transfers` tag has already been created and used fairly extensively for a while now, I'm going to sort through the questions tagged with just `transfer` that really should be tagged with `domain-transfer` and edit them to use the `domain-transfer` tag instead.

I'm also going to edit the tag info for the `transfer` tag to:

> The act of moving data, web-hosting, email, etc...to another location or party. Please add an additional tag to specify what would be transferred (e.g., data, web-hosting, email, etc..). For transferring domains, just use the commonly used [domain-transfer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-transfer) tag alone.

I'm also going to add tag info for the `domain-transfer` tag, which was missing:

> Transferring domains to another registrar, host, DNS provider, or party. Please do not include the [transfer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/transfer/info) tag since that's already implied.

So in summary, since there's an unknown combination of "transfer" tags possible and we can't prevent the `transfer` tag from being recreated, the best we can do is to provide better information on how to qualify it with the addition of another tag, and to re-tag questions asking about domains with the commonly used `domain-transfer` tag.

**Update**:

About 31 questions out of the previous 85 questions tagged with just `transfer` were edited to use the `domain-tansfer` tag instead. Also, when typing "transfer" in the Tags form, the `domain-transfer` tag will appear too.